# how to set folder destination path outside laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I need to set `$destination` path to outside project  need to copy folder from project file to computer location i have already tried using copy directory function

```
public function approovenew()
{
    $source = "themes/call";
    $destination = "/new-theme";
            
    File::copyDirectory(base_path($source), base_path($destination));
}
```

Comment: try `__DIR__` and move backward to the destination

Comment: i need to copy the folder outside project folder not moving

Comment: I meant `File::copyDirectory(__DIR__ . '/../whatever', __DIR__ . '/../../whatever');`

Comment: can you give me a example code of yours i need to copy folder to htdocs

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this it will help you out

```
File::copyDirectory(__DIR__ . '/../whatever'$source, __DIR__ . '/../../$destination');
```

Comment: $source = "E:/XAMPP/htdocs/vshop/themes/call";
        $destination = "E:/new";

Not working

        File::copyDirectory(__DIR__ . $source, __DIR__ . $destination);